# How to call change text size in all fragment of viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change text in fragment of viewpager.

this is my FragmentActivity Code :

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 1000;

    private ViewPager mPager;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_screen_slide, menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_previous).setEnabled(
                mPager.getCurrentItem() > 0);

        MenuItem item = menu
                .add(Menu.NONE,
                        R.id.action_next,
                        Menu.NONE,
                        (mPager.getCurrentItem() == mPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) ? R.string.action_finish
                                : R.string.action_next);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_previous:
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
            return true;

        case R.id.action_next:
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_larger_text_size:
            //call method in fragment setTextSizeLarger()
            return true;
        case R.id.action_smaller_text_size:
            //call method in fragment setTextSizeSmaller()
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

and this my fragment :

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
    private int mPageNumber;
    private TextView tvText1;
    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        tvText1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tvText1.setText(
                getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

        return rootView;
    }

    public void setTextSizeLarger()
    {
        tvText1.setTextSize((float)20);
    }

    public void setTextSizeSmaller()
    {
        tvText1.setTextSize((float)19);
    }

    public int getPageNumber() {
        return mPageNumber;
    }
}
```

what i want to achieve is the menu item larger text and smaller text can works.
if it click will setTextSize all TextView in all fragment.
and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

in your fragments register receiver and when the menu item is clicked and the user select for example large icon send broadcast, something like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_LARG_TEXT);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and in your fragment when you receive broadcast see the action of it and change the text size.

```
BroadcastReceiver onTextSizeChanged = new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // Change the text size here
            }
        };
```

in this way you can also send text size.

another solution is making the fragment add items (text size) to your menu and when it changes, setting user text size. In order to do that you must add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` to your fragments.

Update:

because you have not registered your receiver, you must register it at the `onCreateView` or `onCreate` and unregistere it at the `onDestroy`. this is the register part:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_LARG_TEXT);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(onTextSizeChanged, filter);
```

and unregister is:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(onTextSizeChanged);
```

So simpily logical steps:

1)when user select item send broadcast by using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_LARG_TEXT);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

2) in your fragment declare `onTextSizeChanged` as a receiver and override `onReceive`.

3) register and unregister your receiver (`onTextSizeChanged`) at the mentioned lifecycle.

Comment: oops sorry it nothing happend can you give more complete code, because I never use LocalBroadcastManager before. i update your code Intent intent = new Intent("BROADCAST_LARG_TEXT"); LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);